# Proving that $T:V \rightarrow W$ has a unique adjoint transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators

Let $(V, \langle . , \rangle_{V})$,$(W, \langle . , \rangle_{W})$ be inner product spaces, and let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation. A function $T^{*}: W \rightarrow V$ is called an adjoint of $T$ if $\langle T(x),y \rangle_{W} = \langle x, T^{*}(y) \rangle_{V}$ for all $x \in V$ and $y \in W$.

Show that if $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional, then there is a unique adjoint $T^{*}$ of $T$, and $T^{*}$ is linear.

My approach to this problem was basically one of experimentation, I feel like I need to construct $T^{*}$ in the general sense, so I began by constructing it in a specific case to gain some sort of intuition, but it doesn't seem helpful.

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $W = \mathbb{R}^{3}$, both with standard inner product. Let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be defined as $T(x_{1},x_{2}) = (x_{1},x_{2},x_{1}+x_{2})$.

Then $\langle T(x_{1},x_{2}), (y_{1},y_{2},y_{3}) \rangle = \langle (x_{1},x_{2},x_{1}+x_{2}), (y_{1},y_{2},y_{3}) \rangle = x_{1}y_{1} + x_{2}y_{2} + (x_{1}+x_{2})y_{2} = x_{1}(y_{1}+y_{3}) + x_{2}(y_{2}+y_{3})$

This last expression makes it evident that I want $T^{*}(y_{1},y_{2},y_{3}) = (y_{1}+y_{3},y_{2}+y_{3})$, but from this, I'm not really getting any insight to what it looks like in general.

Answer (score 1):

Hint/sketch: choose orthonormal bases $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_j\}$ of $V$ and $W$, and represent $T$ by a matrix $A$ with respect to these bases. Then, the conjugate transpose $A^*$ will define a function $T^*:W\to V$, and you can use the orthogonality + the definition of the action of a matrix on a basis element to show that $\langle Av_i,w_j\rangle=\langle v_i,A^*w_j\rangle$ for all $i,j$. Then you can expand to all elements of $V$ and $W$ using bilinearity of the inner product, showing $T^*$ really is adjoint to $T$.

Comment: This is the conjugate transpose in general, right?

Comment: @JonathanHebert Yes, my mistake! I was assuming things were over $\Bbb R$. I'll fix that

Comment: Ok, thank you. I do see that using the standard bases on my example does give that result. So the inner product is obviously involved by how the adjoint is defined, but in construction it's involved in a subtle way in that it determines what an orthonormal basis is. I think that was the main issue I was having.

Comment: @JonathanHebert no problem, let me know if you get stuck in the general proof and I can update my answer some. Also, I never addressed uniqueness but that shouldn't be too difficult. I'd recommend using the fact that $\langle v,v_0\rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$ if and only if $v_0=0$.